# Opengl ES 2.0: Why does RenderBufferStorage take different internalFormat than TexImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl-es

So in Opengl ES 2.0 either Renderbuffers or Textures can be used as Framebuffer attachments. However, the documentation has me confused about what internal format to specify if I want the depth attachment to be a texture.

Here is a snippet of the documentation of glCheckFramebufferStatus:

> Color-renderable formats include GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB5_A1, and GL_RGB565. GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is the only depth-renderable format.

Now if I check glRenderBufferStorage it lists the following internalFormats:

> Specifies the color-renderable, depth-renderable, or stencil-renderable format of the renderbuffer. Must be one of the following symbolic constants: GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB565, GL_RGB5_A1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, or GL_STENCIL_INDEX8.

Great some of these match the formats required by Framebuffer attachments. However, if I check TexImage2D the formats are completely different.
InternalFormat:

> Specifies the internal format of the texture. Must be one of the following symbolic constants: GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA

And the type for the texel component:

> Specifies the data type of the texel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1

So it's unclear what to pass to TexImage2D to create a texture suitable for a Framebuffer depth attachment. According to the glCheckFramebufferStatus documentation I'd have to use a RenderBuffer. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Well, it seems I may be reading it right. There is an extension for using depth textures in opengl ES 2.0.  https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt So it seems that in the absence of that extension, you can't use a texture as the Framebuffer depth attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support depth textures. They were introduced in ES 3.0. Aside from the reference documentation, you can also see this in the [press release](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-opengl-es-3.0-specification) (emphasis added):

> greatly enhanced texturing functionality including guaranteed support for floating point textures, 3D textures, **depth textures**, vertex textures, NPOT textures, R/RG textures, immutable textures, 2D array textures, swizzles, LOD and mip level clamps, seamless cube maps and sampler objects

To use depth textures with ES 2.0, your device needs to support the [OES_depth_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt) extension you already found.